# Remote MySQL backup from Windows with Worker file

Tags: mysql, backup

I need a solid remote backup/restore solution for my linux webserver.

- The backup/restore software must run on Windows
- It must connect to a remote worker file (script) that does the actual backup/restore, because remote access to MySQL is prohibited. So backup tools that try to connect from windows directly to the remote web server are not what I want.
- Backups are sent to the local windows machine and there stored
- Restores must also be possible from the windows machine
- Large MySQL database support

I downloaded site-vault pro. It promises exactly what I need, however, it does not work. Besides that, their latest update is 6 years old. I also read that their support is non-existent. So it looks like abandoned software.

Looking for something like that, only something that actually works.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can not have both: No connection from Win2Mysql AND Restore from Win2Mysql. This does not make sense. You propably have to trigger all actions from the MySQL webserver LAMP, most propably?

Comment: No, it's not that there is no connection. It's just that the win application cannot access MySQL directly. So it has to connect via the script. The script acts as a bridge between the win application and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH to forward MySQL port. With OpenSSH (available for Windows) it is as simple as:

```
ssh target_server -L 3306:localhost:3306
```

provided that your MySQL service on the remote server server is listening on localhost:3306, not just on the unix socket, and that your local port 3306 is unoccupied. If local port is occupied, you just use another local port (`-L 3307:...`).

Now, you may connect with standard MySQL tools or any 3rd party tools which support MySQL network protocol to the *local* machine (where you run SSH client) to the local port (first one in the connect command). For example, to backup with standard mysqldump and restore with mysql command line tools:

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u username -p --all-databases > dump.sql
mysql -h localhost -u username -p < dump.sql
```

which you run on your client machine while SSH connection is running.

A connection might be scripted in the backup tool to be called right before taking backup or making a restore and made to disconnect when forwarded socket is closed. It is advised to use RSA or another asymmetric crypto for SSH authentication, and restrict those keys on the server to permit only this kind of activity with them; read SSH manual for that again. With all this, the connect command becomes similar to this:

```
ssh target_server -L 3306:localhost:3306 -i backup_connection.pub sleep 60
```

a `sleep` will be called on the remote, a backup or restore MySQL connection to the mysql service must be then started within 60 seconds or the SSH connection will be terminated, but if the MySQL connection is made within that time, the SSH will not terminate until MySQL is connected.